# Execution sequence of multiple write operations without transactional annotation

Tags: oracle, transactions

I have three methods written in Java doing write operations to DB:

```
public void test() {
    //delete record A from table A 
    a();
    //insert record B from table B to table A
    b();
    //delete record B from table B
    c();
}
```

Is there any possibilities that method c finishes before method b?

I read transactional document but I do not find any sequence issues if I do not use transactional annotation but from the result, it clearly shows method c finishes before method b.

This is a single thread environment. DB is Oracle.

Comment: You didn't specify any language, but in those I may guess by this syntax (Java, C#) all the code lines written one after the other are executed sequentially. It will be different in, for example, JS where all blocking code is executed asynchronously in general.

Comment: A bigger problem is, id B fails, A is already persists in the DB

Comment: @astentx sorry it was written in Java

Comment: This exact code will be executed sequentially. But the outcome depends on the implementation of `a()`, `b()` and `c()`: if they do something asyncronously then their call may pop from the call stack before the actual processing is done.